# Get vertex value on vertex click

Tags: wpf, vb.net, graph-sharp

I've added vertex double click event by

```
For Each v In GraphSimple1.graphlayout.Children
     If TypeOf v Is VertexControl Then
         AddHandler TryCast(v, VertexControl).MouseDoubleClick, AddressOf v_MouseDoubleClick
     End If
Next v
```

it Works well but how can i get vertex value which i've clicked

Comment: What's happening in "v_MouseDoubleClick"

Comment: @David Sdot There i've just put message box but i want to display vertex value in that field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub v_MouseDoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
    MessageBox.Show(Directcast(sender , VertexControl).ID)
End Sub
```

**sender** is your VertexControl so need to cast it to type VertexControl and can use it.